# pegar valor de uma variável JS e colocar em no input value

Tags: php, javascript

preciso colocar o resultado desse javascript no valor do input para o php identificar a variável.

```
var mydate=new Date()
var year=mydate.getYear()
if (year<2000)
year += (year < 1900) ? 1900 : 0
var day=mydate.getDay()
var month=mydate.getMonth()
var daym=mydate.getDate()
if (daym<10)
daym="0"+daym
var dayarray=new Array("Domingo","Segunda-feira","Terça-feira","Quarta-feira","Quinta-feira","Sexta-feira","Sábado")
var montharray=new Array(" de Janeiro de "," de Fevereiro de "," de Março de ","de Abril de ","de Maio de ","de Junho de","de Julho de ","de Agosto de ","de Setembro de "," de Outubro de "," de Novembro de "," de Dezembro de ")
document.write("   "+dayarray[day]+", "+daym+" "+montharray[month]+year+" ")
```

Comment: Bem-vindo, por favor edite sua pergunta, e formate o código, selecione o código e aperta CTRL+K

Comment: Para fazer melhor utilização do site, faça o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e para obter respostas que solucionem sua dúvida / problema leia [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Como formatar minhas publicações usando o Markdown ou HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Não consigo editar

Comment: @BrunoAguiar clicka em [edit] <-- aqui ou no final da pergunta, depois das tags `[php]` e `[javascript]`

Comment: Porquê tag `php` ? Não estamos a falar somente de `javascript` ?

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma campo texto, informando o atributo `name` e `id` no exemplo abaixo coloquei o valor de ambos como `data`

```
<input type="text" name="data" id="data" value="" />
```

altere a última linha do javascript:

```
document.write("   "+dayarray[day]+", "+daym+" "+montharray[month]+year+" ")
```

Para:

```
// Insere a data no campo através do atributo id.
document.getElementById('data').value = dayarray[day]+", "+daym+" "+montharray[month]+year;
```

```js
var mydate=new Date();
var year=mydate.getYear();
if (year<2000)
year += (year < 1900) ? 1900 : 0;
var day=mydate.getDay();
var month=mydate.getMonth();
var daym=mydate.getDate();
if (daym<10)
daym="0"+daym;
var dayarray=new Array("Domingo","Segunda-feira","Terça-feira","Quarta-feira","Quinta-feira","Sexta-feira","Sábado");
var montharray=new Array(" de Janeiro de "," de Fevereiro de "," de Março de ","de Abril de ","de Maio de ","de Junho de","de Julho de ","de Agosto de ","de Setembro de "," de Outubro de "," de Novembro de "," de Dezembro de ");
// Insere a data no campo através do atributo id.
document.getElementById('data').value = dayarray[day]+", "+daym+" "+montharray[month]+year;
```

```html
<input type="text" name="data" id="data" value="" />
```

Comment: TOP HEIM!

obrigado...funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Para atribuir um valor a um input basta fazeres `input.value = 'novo valor';` Mas podes fazer isso simplesmente com [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

Fiz dois exemplos, um com o teu código corrigido, outro com `toLocaleDateString`.

```js
var input1 = document.querySelector('[name="data1"]');
var input2 = document.querySelector('[name="data2"]');

var mydate = new Date()
var year = mydate.getFullYear()
var day = mydate.getDay()
var month = mydate.getMonth()
var daym = mydate.getDate()
if (daym < 10) daym = "0" + daym

var dayarray = ["Domingo", "Segunda-feira", "Terça-feira", "Quarta-feira", "Quinta-feira", "Sexta-feira", "Sábado"];
var montharray = [" de Janeiro de ", " de Fevereiro de ", " de Março de ", "de Abril de ", "de Maio de ", "de Junho de", "de Julho de ", "de Agosto de ", "de Setembro de ", " de Outubro de ", " de Novembro de ", " de Dezembro de "];
input1.value = dayarray[day] + ", " + daym + " " + montharray[month] + year;

input2.value = new Date().toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });
```

```css
input {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="data1" />
<input type="text" name="data2" />
```